# Boost::Test: automatic test suite name generation based on current file name?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

Is there any way to make Boost.Test take the name of the file as automatic test suite name, in a portable manner?

Something like `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(__FILE__)` (this doesn't work because `__FILE__` contains full path and is not a string object).

Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like an anti-pattern for testing. Why do you think this is a convenient thing to do?

Comment: Just following the "don't repeat yourself" principle. I have already named the test suite when I named the file. I shouldn't have to repeat this name in macro invocation.

Comment: But if for the sake of the "don't repeat yourself" principle, everything becomes hard to maintain, error prone, not cross platform, etc, what is the point?

Comment: "There's currently no way to do it in a portable and easy to maintain manner" is a valid answer to my question.